# Last page is blank when using lineno

Tags: lineno

When I include `\usepackage{lineno}` the last page always is rendered blank.

I used [this template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-oxford-bioinformatics-journal-new-version/zjrmbrmtrytg) for the manuscript, but the error doesn't seem to occur with that alone. I couldn't figure out a MWE to include. There isn't even an error or warning in the log file. Any idea what to try next to debug it?

I've gotten around this by using `\cleardoublepage`. It makes an extra page that ends up being empty that I can just delete afterward.

UPDATE: Thanks to @CarLaTeX for the link. It helped me work out an MWE.

```
\documentclass{bioinfo}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[switch]{lineno}

\begin{document}
\linenumbers

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-3]

%\cleardoublepage
\end{document}
```

If I toggle `\cleardoublepage` the page content displays/doesn't. I guess there is something in the `bioinfo.cls` file that conflicts with `lineno`?

Comment: Well, how do you expect an answer to look like if you do not have an MWE?

Comment: If you don't know what an MWE is, see here: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: We're very keen on MWEs around here, you know.

Comment: I got a timeout on overleaf. Do you have a TeX distribution installed on your machine and can you run the file on your own system and _then_ report whatever came out of it? Otherwise I doubt you will get any useful answer on tex.se

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I believe I got an MWE. @thymaro, I can compile it locally as well as on overleaf.

Comment: If I try with the example file in the distribution, the last page gets mangled and ejected blank. This is due, I believe, to the routine for balancing the columns in the final page which conflicts with `\lineno`. With `\cleardoublepage` the balancing is not perfect, but it can be accepted for a provisional version with line numbers.